# Unable to build SparkSession in Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark, and I'm using it in a jupyter notebook. I have the following code, which gives me an error:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Epidemiology").config(conf = SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
```

I'm at a loss here, any suggestions as to what could be the problem?
The complete error is too long to post here, but this is part of it:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

C:\spark\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.sessionState.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1053)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:129)
.
.
.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-17a54aa52bc2> in <module>()
      1 # Boilerplate Spark stuff
      2 #conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Epidemiology")
----> 3 spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Epidemiology").config(conf = SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
      4 #sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf = conf)
      5 #sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    177                     session = SparkSession(sc)
    178                 for key, value in self._options.items():
--> 179                     session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
    180                 for key, value in self._options.items():
    181                     session.sparkContext._conf.set(key, value)

C:\spark\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I ended up not using sparksession, in fact I did not use pyspark.sql at all in the end because I couldn't get it to work. So I just have:

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

Comment: I am facing the same exact error as above. Any help / pointers is greatly appreciated!